# Check keys in list of dictionaries and create new lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list `p` and and a list of dictionaries `q` like below.

```
p = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
q = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'b':3, 'c':4},{'c':5,'a':6},
      {'d':7,'a':8}]
```

`p` and `q` are of the same length always.

I want an output of lists that looks like the below.

```
a = [1,2,0,0]
b = [0,3,4,0]
c = [6,0,5,0]
d = [8,0,0,7]
```

I have tried the below

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []

for i in range(len(p)):
    if p[i] == q[i].keys():
        a.append(q[i].values())
    else:
        a.append(0)
```

and so on and so forth for all the empty lists, but it does not seem to append the value to the list.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO isn't a code-writing service

Comment: Also : explain the rationale behind the goal

Answer (score 6):

You can use unpacking:

```
p = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
q = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'b':3, 'c':4},{'c':5,'a':6}, {'d':7,'a':8}]
a, b, c, d = [[i.get(c, 0) for c in p] for i in q]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0, 0]
[0, 3, 4, 0]
[6, 0, 5, 0]
[8, 0, 0, 7]
```